# Polickit - how to suspend machine

Tags: debian, polkit

On my desktop computer running Debian Sid I have polkitd in 123-3

Each time I try to suspend my machine from regular user I have a prompt window for 'root password'.

I already had it working few months ago, and now after some upgrade it again prompts for root password.

Previously I have added custom entry in:
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/30-emil-suspend.rules

```
polkit.addRule(function(action) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.suspend") == 0 &&
      subject.local && subject.active && subject.user == "emil") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
});
```

It seem that there is no effect from this script.

1. How can I debug policykit?
2. How can normal user do that? Is there some sort of UI for policyki ?